# Read filenames of directory in Spark

Tags: java, file, spark-java

I want to list all files of one directory. However, I can't find the files with the **relative** path. With the absolute path this works perfectly.

Here is my file structure:

[image: My file structure]

I have already set the static path and use it successfully with the css, and js files:

```
staticFiles.location("/public");
File f = new File("data/fJSON/f.json");
//File f = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\mS\\src\\main\\resources\\public\\data\\fJSON\\f.json");
try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String st;
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(st);
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that the code should currently read only one specific file, which only works with the absolute path and not with the relative path.

What did I misconfigure or overlook about the path? What do I have to change so that the file can be read via the relative path?

Comment: Usually resources are not on the file system, they are **in** a jar.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thank you. It is a duplicate since the solution is presented in the other question.